# Simple elapsed time counter

Tags: javascript, datetime, formatting

I've written a simple JavaScript function based off some existing code that takes a specific UNIX time string (in the snippet: `1491685200`). It shows an alert if the specified time is still in the future. When that date has passed, it shows the elapsed days, hours and minutes whenever the function is called in-page.

I'm don't have much JavaScript object experience so it works just fine as-is, but I think it can be optimized further before I migrate my other stuff over to ES6.

```
function ElapsedTime () {
  var nTotalDiff = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) - 1491685200;
  if (nTotalDiff >= 0) {
    var oDiff = {};
    oDiff.days = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 86400);
    nTotalDiff -= oDiff.days * 86400;
    oDiff.hours = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 3600);
    nTotalDiff -= oDiff.hours * 3600;
    oDiff.minutes = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 60);
    nTotalDiff -= oDiff.minutes * 60;
    oDiff.seconds = Math.floor(nTotalDiff);
    return oDiff;
  } else {
    alert('nTotalDiff still not >=0, so must be before the specified date');
  }
}

function TimePassed() {
  oDiff = ElapsedTime();
  if(oDiff) {
    alert(oDiff.days + 'd ' + oDiff.hours + 'h ' + oDiff.minutes + 'm ');
  }
}

//   document.getElementById('counter').addEventListener('click', TimePassed, false);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Remarks to your code

- Function names should be using camelCase.
- Two minor formatting errors: `function ElapsedTime ()`, `if(oDiff)`.
                                                 `↑       ↑`
- You mentioned ES6 in your question, so: `var nTotalDiff` could be declared using `let` and `var oDiff` using `const`.
- You declare `oDiff` in `TimePassed()` as a global variable (you forgot `var`).
- `oDiff.seconds` is declared, but never used.
- `(new Date())` can be written as `new Date()`.
- <s>Specifying `1491685200` in human readable format would be better, I think.</s>
  <sub>Update: suggestion removed due to the problem pointed out in the comment to this answer.</sub>
- If you leverage power of modulo operator, you can get rid of all these `nTotalDiff -= oDiff.██████ * ███`.
- `alert(oDiff.days + 'd ' + oDiff.hours + 'h ' + oDiff.minutes + 'm ')` can be written in ES6 using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as `` alert(`${oDiff.days}d ${oDiff.hours}h ${oDiff.minutes}m `) ``, although space after `m` is unnecessary whatsoever.
- Having two functions named `ElapsedTime()` and `TimePassed()` seem ambiguous.
- Your code is not in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

### My rewrite

```js
const elapsedTime = () => {
  'use strict';
  const since   = 1491685200000, // Saturday, 08-Apr-17 21:00:00 UTC
        elapsed = (new Date().getTime() - since) / 1000;

  if (elapsed >= 0) {
    const diff = {};

    diff.days    = Math.floor(elapsed / 86400);
    diff.hours   = Math.floor(elapsed / 3600 % 24);
    diff.minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60 % 60);
    diff.seconds = Math.floor(elapsed % 60);

    let message = `Over ${diff.days}d ${diff.hours}h ${diff.minutes}m ${diff.seconds}s.`;
    message = message.replace(/(?:0. )+/, '');
    alert(message);
  }
  else {
    alert('Elapsed time lesser than 0, i.e. specified datetime is still in the future.');
  }
};

document.getElementById('counter').addEventListener('click', elapsedTime, false);
```

```html
<button id="counter">Check elapsed time</button>
```

#### Remarks

- `/(?:0. )+/` matches sequences of one or more zero followed by any character and a space. It is used to change potential output that would look like `0d 0h 0m 1s` to simply `1s`.
- In `message` I added word *over*, because the calculated time is in fact the least amount of time that could have passed (calculation time, `Math.floor()`, instantaneous nature of time specification invalidation).

Comment: Hi @Przemek, thanks for the remarks. However, the dateString you specified (`Saturday, 08-Apr-17 21:00:00 UTC`), without modification, didn't work (dashes between day/month/year, `NaN`) thus causing `elapsed` to always be <0. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) recommends to just use a ISO8601 string (`2017-04-08 21:00:00Z`) or a UNIX timestamp (`1491685200000`), dependent on user preference of course.

Comment: @rctgamer3: Hey there. Now that I have read a bit more deeply I have found that ISO8601 is indeed preferred over RFC2822, although I even found the following quote: *because of the variances in parsing of date strings, it is recommended to always manually parse strings as results are inconsistent, especially across different ECMAScript implementations*. As such I have edited the hardcoded `1491685200000` back in. I guess you learn something new everyday ;), thanks for the comment.